# cant use like clause in android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a database with sqllite in an android app
I want to retrieve sm data using a like clause
ex:

```
Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, null, " SongName LIKE '%"+"=?"+"%'" , 
           new String[]{match_str}, null, null,"SongHit  DESC");
```

It should give all SongName starting with match_str but its not working.Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This:

```
" SongName LIKE '%"+"=?"+"%'"
```

Will end up looking like this when the SQL interpreter sees it:

```
" SongName LIKE '%=?%'"
```

And that will match any SongName that contains a literal "=?" and I don't think that's anything like what you want.

A `%` matches any sequence of characters in an SQL LIKE, it is essentially the same as `.*` in a regular expression; so, if you want to match at the beginning then you don't want a leading `%`. Also, your `?` placeholder needs to be outside the single quotes or it will be interpreted as a literal question mark rather than a placeholder.

You want something more like this:

```
String[] a = new String[1];
a[0]       = match_str + '%';
Cursor   c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE SongName LIKE ?", a);
```

If you wanted to be really strict you'd also have to escape `%` and `_` symbols inside `match_str` as well but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: i am dvlping an andr app with an edittext which enables users to search songs.i want to use  instant srch  in it i mean i want the search results in my listview of my app instantly as the user types in the edittext box in order of most visited songs . i am using a DB of songs for it but i am afraid it may be too slow.Besides i want my edittext listner to slow down and wait till the user completes his text  i am using System.currentTimeMillis() as marker nd wait fr .5 sec bt its not waiting . i am new to android and dont know wheather it will work or not .. pls suggest me smthing

Comment: @user712771: That sounds like a whole new question that would be better answered by someone that knows Android better than I do.

Comment: thanks ,  but i really thought u could help..i think i should ask it as a separate question..

Comment: @user712771: I'm not that great with Android, I'm just trying to help you understand what you did wrong, [teach a man to fish](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/2279.html) and all that.

Comment: Great Explaination, helps understand why it works and a direct way doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
String[] args = new String[1];
args[0] = "%"+song+"%";
Cursor friendLike = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE SongName like ?", args);
```

Comment: I think you want `args[0] = song+"%";` as they say "starting with...".

Comment: thats true, only use a % after the argument to get the **starts with**

Comment: great it worked fine...however i didi't understood  why the solution above didnt worked.

Comment: i am developing an android app with an editbox which enables users

Comment: Nice work, helps lot of user hanging around over here stuck in the Like problem

Answer (score 1):

No need for the equal sign and you should be able to include the ? right in the string without the need for the + operator. The where clause should just be:

```
"SongName LIKE '%?%'"
```

and if mu is too short is correct and you only want starting with...

```
"SongName LIKE '?%'"
```

Comment: I think you need to drop the single quotes around `?` to make it a placeholder rather than a string literal.

Comment: thanks mu, you're right. I haven't really used the ? and selection args in my own queries so I wasn't 100% clear on their usage...

Answer (score 0):

hi Are you getting any exception while executing the above query. Try by removing the "=" symbol infront of the question mark in the like condition. Else try using

```
db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me...

```
"Songname LIKE ? "...

cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + searchTerm + "%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use `query()` instead of `rawQuery()`, you can do it like so:

```
// searchString is the string to search for
final String whereClause = "MyColumnName" + " like ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"%" + searchString + "%"};

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("MyTableName",
        null, // columns
        whereClause, // selection
        whereArgs, // selectionArgs
        null, // groupBy
        null, // having
        null, // orderBy
        null); // limit
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to use the concatenate operator ||

```
"SongName LIKE '%'||?||'%'"
```

so there is no need to edit the match_str.

```
Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, null, " SongName LIKE '%'||?||'%'" , 
       new String[]{match_str}, null, null,"SongHit  DESC");
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46420813/908821