# Android SQLite select * from table where name like %key% using prepared statements

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, prepared-statement

I want to use prepared statements to prevent sql injections on Android SQLite database. However, rawquery crashes when the query  contains `Like` and works with `Where name = ?`
is there a way to use like and prepared statements in Android SQLite db ?

This is the query:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CALLS + " where " + CALLER_NAME + " like ? COLLATE NOCASE or " + CALLER_NBR + " like ? or " + CALLER_EXT + " like ?" + " or " + IS_OUTGOING + " like ?  COLLATE NOCASE or " + TYPE + " like ? COLLATE NOCASE";

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, new String[]{"%" + criterion + "%", "%" + criterion + "%","%" + criterion + "%","%" + criterion + "%","%" + criterion + "%"});
```

it gives a bind or column index out of range
Thank you.

Comment: you may check this to use "Like" in sql query 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752575/cant-use-like-clause-in-android-app

Comment: Like will work with rawquery, can you post your code and log so that we can see what error your getting...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
    if (name.length() != 0) {

        name = "%" + name + "%";
    }
    if (email.length() != 0) {
        email = "%" + email + "%";
    }
    if (Phone.length() != 0) {
        Phone = "%" + Phone + "%";
    }
    String selectQuery = " select * from tbl_Customer where Customer_Name like  '"
            + name
            + "' or Customer_Email like '"
            + email
            + "' or Customer_Phone like '"
            + Phone
            + "' ORDER BY Customer_Id DESC";

    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);`
```

Comment: Thank you, the trick was by checking for empty strings. saved my day. in normal queries, the empty string doesn't cause a problem, but with prepared statements, IT DOES.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery, new String[]{"'%" + criterion + "%'", 
   "'%" + criterion + "%'",
   "'%" + criterion + "%'",
   "'%" + criterion + "%'",
   "'%" + criterion + "%'"});
```

You are missing the " ' " before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Try like..

```
String[] a = new String[5];
a[0]       = '%' + criterion + '%';
a[1]       = '%' + criterion + '%';
a[2]       = '%' + criterion + '%';
a[3]       = '%' + criterion + '%';
a[4]       = '%' + criterion + '%';
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlQuery,a);
```

Comment: I have tried it, still the same probelm. android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x1001a58